# Neopixle animation help

Tags: programming

Ok I'm stupid when it comes to coding. I have a simple project that I need some help with. Is it possible to make neopixle change what animation runs via multiple switches. Example they stay off till switch is flipped then if a different switch is flipped they run a different animation and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: There is too much unspecific language (e.g. "change what animation runs", "stay off") that it's hard to work out what you are actually asking. Also no need to write at the start of your post "I'm stupid when it comes to coding".  You're not, everyone has problems to solve, that's why this site exists.  Consider editing your question also taking into account VE7JRO's comment.

Comment: I get so confused with this stuff lol. What I wanted is the pixels to stay off then when a switch is flipped it does a color wipe and they stay on. Then if another switch is flipped they do a continuous color wipe. And the same in the reverse sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely it is possible. As a beginner, I suggest something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faXJm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In your `setup` you will need to declare D4 - D7 as [inputs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/pinmode/). I have used D4 - D7 but you can choose whatever pins are available.

Then in the `loop` part of the code you want to look for the rising edge on the input (ie when the switch is pressed). [Switch debounce](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/debouncing) is less important for this application as it is not a counter but rather a mode change.

I have written a good [answer for detecting a button press here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/48307/19409).

Nick Gammon has an excellent switch tutorial [gammon.com.au/switches](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches) that covers all kinds of conceivable situations (high or low, GND or +5V, internal pull-up or pull-down, capacitor debounce or software debounce, etc.)

I would imagine the code would look something like this:

```
if( digitalRead(SW1) == HIGH )
    mode = 1;

if( digitalRead(SW2) == HIGH )
    mode = 2;

if( digitalRead(SW3) == HIGH )
    mode = 3;

if( digitalRead(SW4) == HIGH )
    mode = 4;
```

You could then use a [switch-case statement](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/) to run the various NeoPixel patterns.

For more programming reference see: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/

Comment: Thanx makes it much more understandable

Comment: This is driving me nuts lol. does anyone know somewhere i can pay someone to write arduino code.

Comment: The [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/) has a Gigs and Collaborations section where you can offer to pay to have code written for you. However if you just want a fancy light show, you can buy those off the shelf, if you aren't interested in learning the programming side of things.

Comment: I would like to learn it. Just got frustrated with it for a awheil. I'm trying to make lights for a golf cart. Just like a car has stop,tail,and turn signals. I get  close then mess it up to the point it doesn't work anymore lol

Comment: We can do code reviews here on Arduino Stack Exchange. Just add the `code review` tag to the question you ask.

Comment: @Gcompston is there a (part of a) video of something similar to what you want to achieve?